# Why my Angular form won't load the data provided?

Tags: angular

I am following a certain PDF file as a tutorial and i am doing things exactly the same way like it says but i don't get the same result and i don't know what else to do. I googled everything but i can't find what am i doing wrong.

This is student.component.html:

```
<app-student-details [student_child]="student_parent"></app-student-details>
<button (click)="klikni">Klikni</button>
<div *ngIf="this.prikaziDetalje==true">
    <app-student-details [student_child]="student_parent" (dogadjaj)="ucitajDetalje($event)">        
    </app-student-details>
</div>
```

student.component.ts:

```
export class StudentComponent implements OnInit {
  student_parent: Student={
    studentId: 1,
    ime: 'name',
    prezime: 'lastname',
    brojIndeksa: '11/11/11',
    statusBudzeta: 1,
    godinaStudiranja: 3,
    aktivan: true
  }  
  prikaziDetalje: boolean;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  ucitajDetalje(prikaz:boolean)
  {
    this.prikaziDetalje = prikaz
  }
  klikni()
  {
    this.prikaziDetalje = true
  }

}
```

student-details.component.ts:

```
export class StudentDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  student_child: Student

  @Output()
  dogadjaj=new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  proslediPrikazDetalja: boolean;

  constructor() { }
   
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  ugasiDetalje()
  {
    this.proslediPrikazDetalja=false
    this.dogadjaj.emit(this.proslediPrikazDetalja)
  }

}
```

app.component.html:

```
   <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    <app-student></app-student>
```

and student-details.component.html:

```
<label>Ime:</label><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<label>Prezime:</label><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<label>Broj Indeksa:</label><br>
<input type="text"><br>
<label>Godina studiranja:</label><br>
<input type="number"><br>
<label>Status Budžeta:</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="statusBudzeta">Budžet <br>
<input type="radio" name="statusBudzeta">Samofinansiranje<br>
<label>Aktivan:</label><br>   
<input type="checkbox">Aktivan<br>
<button>Sačuvaj</button>
<button>Obriši</button><br>
<hr>
<br><br>
<button (click)="ugasiDetalje()">Zatvori</button>
```

I imported the Output, Input and EventEmitter in student-details component as well, and this should be the result:

[image: a title with a button to "show" underneath]

and clicking on the button i should get something like this

[image: after clicking on the "show" button]

but instead i get this and buttons "Klikni" and "Zatvori" don't work.

[image]

What am i doing wrong? I literally keep oing the exact same thing from this tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in this line: `<button (click)="klikni">Klikni</button>`

You need to actually *invoke* `klikni`: `(click)="klikni()"` (note the parenthesis).

As for the empty controls in `StudentDetailsComponent` in your template (HTML file) you have declared a number of controls but have not actually assigned the values in your `student_child` variable to those controls.

For example, you have written:

```
<label>Ime:</label><br>
<input type="text"><br>
```

Compare that to something like:

```
<label>Ime:</label><br>
<input type="text" [value]="student_child.ime"><br> // Binds the value to the control
```

This approach above of populating controls with data is very crude, though.

I would suggest looking into using [Angular Forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview) as it streamlines the process of data binding and also has a bunch of features for improving on the UI/UX.

Comment: I'll definitely look into it once i finish updating this version of Angular... Apparently, somehow, i have a lot older version, so could that be the reason the app is not working? P.S. Nevermind the button, all fields should be filled with the data that i provided, but instead they are empty. Even before i added the button all of the fields should be filled. That doesn't work either.

Comment: I doubt your Angular version would be causing this - it's likely an issue in the code.
You say "Nevermind the button..." but actually, in the code you posted that button is important. The `app-student-details` component only gets shown when `prikaziDetalje` is `true` due to: `*ngIf="this.prikaziDetalje==true`. But `prikaziDetalje` will only be set to true when `klikni()` is invoked.

Comment: Yes, "prikaziDetalje" is invoked by "klikni", an i did change the code like you told me, but instead that was reported as an error. When i changed it back to the way it already was, it compiled succesfully. The thing that interest me now is why won't the data in "StudentDetailsComponent" get loaded to the form like it's shown in the image. The code remains the same, but for now that's what interests me more. That should be done first, an then i'll commit to why the buttons don't work.

Comment: What error did it give you? I think you are misunderstanding, I already explained "why won't the data in "StudentDetailsComponent" get loaded to the form like it's shown in the image" - it's because of `*ngIf="this.prikaziDetalje==true`. This line of code says "only show this component if `prikaziDetalje` is equal to `true`". It won't be true though until you press the `klikni` button (as you can see from the `klikni()` method.

Comment: I edited the code once more and you were right, i was missing the paranthesis. But now the thing is that when i invoke the `klikni()` method, it shows another empty form below the one i already have. The result should be a _title_ and below it a _"Klikni" button_, so when i invoke it, it should show the **form which is filled with the data i provided in StudentDetailsComponent.**

Comment: You'll need to provide more code in your question then as I cannot see the template (HTML file) for `app.component.html or `student-details.component.html`. Please edit your question and include these so I can help further.

Comment: I just added more code, so feel free to take a look.

Comment: Thanks, I see the problem now. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The thing is i'm doing the **EXACT** same thing as it's written in this .pdf, nothing else. I hope i won't get any more troubles that weren't written in here.

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to help. In that case, perhaps use a more reliable tutorial. The official Angular [docs](https://angular.io/docs) have loads of information and it's kept up-to-date fairly frequently.

Comment: I will have to do that. Thank you.